# Content of File PHP

Tags: php, file, binary

I have a file that i opened:

`$linie = file("hasla-kopia.txt");` (It's in Polish)

And i have a problem with getting content of a file where every element is in the next line.
This is how my file looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvpgb.png)

I want the exact output on my php file. I know you can do it by nl2br() function but it's really important for me to make every element in a different HTML tag because i want my final output to be:

1000111011111 in decimal system is: *some number*

and I don't know how to do the content on separate lines, change to int and write this text after it. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking or what the issue is. Can't you just loop through each line in the file?

Comment: how about exploding lines int an array by new line char? like `$arr=explode(chr(10), $linie);` ? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: When i loop it puts content in one HTML tag and I can't write any text after every number. The text just writes in the end of tag

Comment: `When i loop it puts content in one HTML tag and I can't write any text after every number`...a loop by itself doesn't do that. It must be some consequence of how you've written the code inside the loop. Show your code please

Comment: Also it would help us to test your code if you simply paste the contents of the text file into your question. A picture of it is not useful for that. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where it specifically mentions not to include pictures of your code and data - they are text, and should be provided as text.

Comment: for ($i=0; $i<count($linie); $i++) {

                echo "<h6>$linie[$i]</h6>";
               

            }

Comment: Ok. There's nothing which would stop you writing something else inside those tags.

Comment: e.g. `for ($i=0; $i<count($linie); $i++) { echo "<h6>$linie[$i] in decimal system is: some number</h6>"; }`

Comment: It still doesn’t work and i don't know why

Comment: define "doesn't work". What exactly is wrong? Does it print the extra text I added?

Comment: Also please show the code where you actually read data from the file.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn’t make next line and it writes number in the same line and my only line of code is: $linie = file('hasla.txt');

Comment: Are you viewing this output in a web browser?

Answer (score 1):

```
$lines = file('hasla-kopia.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo $line."<br>";
}
```

that allows reading line by line and each line is the variable `$line`

Comment: It  still writes on the same line

Comment: silentd How about showing us a part of the output and come to that the code you are using to get whatever result you are getting :) That may make the question a bit easier to provide a good answer for

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$file = file_get_contents("hasla-kopia.txt");

$em = explode("\n" , $file);

for($i=0;$i<count($em);$i++){

echo $em[$i];

};
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: still doesn't work unfortunately